# gradle build for kotlin code

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to set up a project building Kotlin code with Gradle. I've followed instructions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) on how to set up the build.gradle file but am receiving an error

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
```

With this I get the error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'kjsonparser'.
>     Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>     Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.
>      Required by:
>          project :
>     Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.
>     Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.0.pom'.
>     Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.0.pom'.
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

I've also tried the "newer" way of specifing the plugin

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.0"
}
```

Which gives this error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.2.0'] was not found in any >of the following sources:
>
> Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
>   - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact >'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.2.0')
>    Searched in the following repositories:
>      Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Version of Gradle

```
gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4
```

Kotlin (and openjdk)
    kotlin -version
    Kotlin version 1.2.0 (JRE 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)

Running on Ubuntu 17.10

I've never worked with Gradle before so not sure if I'm missing anything in the build file

Comment: Looks like this should work - are you sure your internet connection is working properly? The error indicates a problem with this

Comment: Yes definitely connected to the internet and I am able to wget the repo.maven.appache.org link from the OP

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never use the `buildscript` block.
Try this instead:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.31'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.31'
}
```